# contentStartItem site setting in Sitecore 9.1

Tags: configuration

This seems like a very simple config. Set the **`contentStartItem`** path that is below the **`rootPath`**. In this case it is the `home` item below the `/sitecore/content/Sites/Client` path.

When I log in as an editor, I land on the `/Sitecore/Content/home` item and not the `/sitecore/content/Sites/Client/home` item. I wonder if this functionality is broken in 9.1.

```
<site name="client" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
      targetHostName="client.dev.local"
      hostName="client.dev.local"
      database="web"
      virtualFolder="/"
      physicalFolder="/"
      rootPath="/sitecore/content/Sites/Client"
      startItem="/home"
      contentStartItem="/home"
      domain="client"
      allowDebug="true"
      cacheHtml="true"
      htmlCacheSize="50MB"
      registryCacheSize="0"
      viewStateCacheSize="0"
      xslCacheSize="25MB"
      filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB"
      enablePreview="true"
      enableWebEdit="true"
      enableDebugger="true"
      disableClientData="false"
      cacheRenderingParameters="true"
      renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB"
      loginPage="/login"
      enableItemLanguageFallback="true" />
</sites>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contentStartItem` site property is used when you open `Content Editor` this is the item which will be selected by default when you open it.

Sitecore reads site definitions in the order they appear in showconfig. In 99% cases, then first site will be `shell` site:

```xml
<site 
    name="shell"
    virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" 
    physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content" 
    startItem="/home" 
    ...
/>
```

When you open `Content Editor`, the url is

> `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1`

which matches the shell site.

If you have a config patch like:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site 
        name="shell" 
        contentStartItem="/Sites/Client/home"
        />
      </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

then every time you open `Content Editor` it will load `/sitecore/content/Sites/Client/home` initially.

Comment: You are exactly right with that patch. BUT I would expect that I could have a different contentStartItem  for each site the user logs into. Doesn't seem very multi-site compliant. When I remove the contentStartItem from shell, doesn't fall through to the client site. When I move the client site above shell, well that causes all those problems.

Comment: I totally agree. It would be nice to view Content Editor in certain site context

Comment: I've not tried, but I think it would be possible to make inherited "shell" sites, each with different contentStartItem settings, responding to their own hostName. After all, the Content Editor is just another site in the solution.